# Proving that ${k\tan}^{-1}(x) = x$ has exactly zero as a solution when $k < 1$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Prove that if $k < 1$ then the equation ${k\tan}^{-1}(x) = x$ has only zero as a solution. For $k =0$, it is trivial, but how about the others?

Comment: Try considering the derivative of $k\tan^{-1} x -x$.

Comment: @Tavish That was really easy. Thanks.